# iTunes Redownload Music

Tags: music, itunes-store

I have purchased an album in iTunes, but it still shows the price in the store. Does this mean that the next time I want to redownload the music I'll need to pay for it again?

I have experienced purchased apps with iTunes, and I didn't need to repurchase the items. But for the music album, I'm not sure about the rules of purchase.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should be able to re-download iTunes purchases for free. Perhaps that isn't the exact same album? For popular artists, iTunes often has multiple compilations/reissues that are all technically unique albums even though they appear to be the same.

Comment: But as the screenshot i shown. It still show the price. I afraid to click it again. It may charge me again @_@

Comment: No, don't click it again. What I'm saying is that the album that you're looking at in the store might not be the exact one that you purchased. Try this: on the homepage of the store, click Purchased on the right under Quick Links. Then select ABBA from the list on the left. You should be able to re-download the album from there for free.

Comment: @daGUY I'm pretty sure it the same album. I have the copy of the album in my iTunes after purchase it.

Answer (score 2):

A while back (maybe two years ago), I ran into the same situation.  I had to e-mail apple support before I could re-download it.  They warned me, saying that I should make backups, and that next time I would have to purchase the music again.  As it turns out, I actually did lose the music a second time (because I was an idiot), and sure enough they wouldn't let me re-download it.

Perhaps their policy has changed now that cloud computing was so prevalent, but it may be worth a try e-mailing them.

Comment: Do you have apple email address where i can report this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that iTunes in the cloud isn't available in the country where your Apple store account is located.

See this article that explains how to re-download content for free:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519

It has a linked article that lists the countries where this service is available:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5085

So, if your account is based in Anguila or Armenia - you are good to go, but if you are based from Albania or Angola you need to pay each time you download the music.